# Unwanted slug in my website

Tags: redirect, slug

There is an unwanted slug `/question/` in my WordPress website. Slugs are automatically changed to `/question/` when I open many pages. I have thoroughly checked my phpMyAdmin and I have no `/question/` slug on my website. My `.htaccess` also have nothing other than standard piece of code.

Though I have a custom post type `/questions/` but it does seem to be a problem.

It's very very annoying because when I open my custom login page `www.ideabroad.com/sign-in/`, it also change to `www.ideabroad.com/question/`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the code that you use for rewriting your custom post type URL's

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your canonical URL is set to http://www.ideabroad.com/question/. I suspect your Yoast SEO plugin is doing this. You need to reconfigure it appropriately.